# Location and heading not working

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, core-location, cllocationmanager

I downloaded the source code of [this](http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/18/ios-core-location-gps-tutorial-pt-2/) tutorial and played a bit with it.
All working fine.

Now I wanted to create my own project to implement location and heading. But after writing all, it does not work. I don't even see a GPS indication on the top.

When I run the other app, its al fine.
Xcode does not give any errors or warnings.

my code:
(it did not change anything in the AppDelegate).

LocationAndHeadingTestViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LocationController.h"

@interface LocationAndHeadingTestViewController : UIViewController <LocationControllerDelegate>
{
    LocationController *_locationController;

    IBOutlet UILabel *_errorLabel;

    //Location
    IBOutlet UILabel *_locationTimeLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *_latitudeLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *_longitudeLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *_altitudeLabel;

    //Heading
    IBOutlet UILabel *_headingTimeLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *_trueHeadingLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *_magneticHeadingLabel;
    IBOutlet UILabel *_headingAccuracyLabel;

    IBOutlet UIImageView *_compass;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) LocationController *locationController;

@end
```

LocationAndHeadingTestViewController.m

```
#import "LocationAndHeadingTestViewController.h"

@implementation LocationAndHeadingTestViewController

@synthesize locationController = _locationController;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _locationController = [LocationController new];
    _locationController.delegate = self;
    [_locationController.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [_locationController.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
}


- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location 
{
    [_locationTimeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", location.timestamp]];
    [_latitudeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude]];
    [_longitudeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude]];
    [_altitudeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [location altitude]]];
}

- (void)headingUpdate:(CLHeading *)heading
{
    [_headingTimeLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", heading.timestamp]];
    [_trueHeadingLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", heading.trueHeading]];
    [_magneticHeadingLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", heading.magneticHeading]];
    [_headingAccuracyLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", heading.headingAccuracy]];
}

- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error 
{
    _errorLabel.text = [error description];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)viewDidUnload 
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [_locationController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

LocationController.h

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol LocationControllerDelegate
@required

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location;
- (void)headingUpdate:(CLHeading *)heading;
- (void)locationError:(NSError *)error;

@end

@interface LocationController : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *_locationManager;
    id _delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;

@end
```

LocationController.m

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "LocationController.h"

@implementation LocationController

@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager, delegate = _delegate;

- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init]) 
    {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager new] autorelease];
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(LocationControllerDelegate)]) 
    {
        [self.delegate locationUpdate:newLocation];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(LocationControllerDelegate)]) 
    {
        [_delegate locationError:error];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    if([self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(LocationControllerDelegate)]) 
    {
        [_delegate headingUpdate:newHeading];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [_locationManager release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

It is fairly simple but I think I really overlook something.

Ps. I will change the id delegate to id <..> delegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be autoreleasing the CLLocationManager object:

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager new] autorelease];
```

That's a "retain" property.  You need to remove the autorelease, you are going to release it in the dealloc.  You can only release it once.

If you had assigned it using the setter, then the setter would have retained it for you.  Like this would be OK:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager new] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your app enabled for location service in the iPhone settings?

Location service (global access) can be on but your specific app in the location service settings could also be denied location access at the same time.